# <a> link tags on site shifting around on click?

Tags: html, css

Our whole site (running bootstrap v3) has an issue with  link tags where when clicked, it sometimes doesn't visit the page on that first click and instead it shifts slightly down and to the left, pushing other elements with it.

Example:
[Before click on  tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw3Iq.png)

[After click on  tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sRLS.png)

I've tried using `Display: block;` and `Display: inline-block;` but that hasn't helped. There is no issue if I were to replace these as  tags (nothing shifts around), but I shouldn't have to use  tags.

I've never encountered this issue before so if anyone has dealt with this or might know what could be causing it, any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try display:block on a:active. define definite height and width to links. It is hard to determine the issue since you haven't posted any code, but I am sure this will fix it.